# How can I create a popup that fits its content perfectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is very hard, and I also tried many "solutions" on the web, but none of those actually fit perfectly. I have a hard time calculating its outer frame's dimensions, but luckily I can sort of know what is the dimension of the content inside by making the `body` float left.

```
body{       /*Or div*/
    float: left;
}

ctnWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
ctnHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
```

Is there a perfect way (or a better way) to achieve it and fits it perfectly? (not necessarily cross browser) Since I can't find any answers on Google.

Thanks.

Comment: If you do not specific a width or height to a div, it will be the exact size needed to fit it's content, provided the internal content has no floats.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already having `jquery` i would suggest you to make use of `jquery`. try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).width($('#mydiv').width());
    $(window).height($('#mydiv').height());
});
```